# Getting Members of Local Administrator Group on Devices Joined to AAD

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, intune

Is there a way (through a Intune Remediation, Powershell script, or possibly Microsoft Graph) to query every Azure AD joined device and export the members of the local administrators group?  We have users that were joined to our Azure AD with their devices and while some were removed from local administrator status via the net localgroup command, others were never removed.  I am trying to find out what users have local administrator rights to their computers without have to manually touch each device.

Thanks in advance!

Jonathan

I found a "proactive remediation" script online and tried using that script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both detect and fix stuff with remediation scripts, so you could first roll out a detection only script to find the devices with extra users in the Administrators group, then you could find out who actually should have the admin rights, then create a fix remediation script, exclude the devices that should have local admin, and deploy out a removal script to the rest. If you left that script running forever, then it would continually empty out the local admins group on all the devices not excluded.

For the detection script you could try something like:

```
Try {
$AdminMembers = Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators
$NonDefaultAdminAccounts = $AdminMembers | Where-Object Name -notmatch '\\Administrator$'
IF ($NonDefaultAdminAccounts) 
    {
    Write-Output "Extra admin members found: $($NonDefaultAdminAccounts.Name -join ',')"
    exit 1
    } else 
        {
        Write-Output "No extra admin members found"
        exit 0
        }
} Catch 
    {
    Write-Output "Detection script failed, error: $($_.exception.message)"
    exit 1
    }
```

And for the removal script something like:

```
Try {
$AdminMembers = Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators
$NonDefaultAdminAccounts = $AdminMembers | Where-Object Name -notmatch '\\Administrator$'
Foreach ($Member in $NonDefaultAdminAccounts)
{
    Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member $Member
}
Write-Output "Extra admin members removed"
Exit 0
} Catch 
    {
    Write-Output "Failed to remove extra admin members, error: $($_.exception.message)"
    exit 1
    }
```

Test it out on a few devices first though, before going to large numbers.

Comment: We have also local admin account on the devices that's named ADMINS, so we basically have two admin accounts that should be there.  That being the case, how would we modify the detection script to include both the built-in Administrator account and additional ADMINS account?

Comment: I've used match on the command so you could update the regex like this:

`$NonDefaultAdminAccounts = $AdminMembers | Where-Object Name -notmatch '\\Administrator$|\\ADMINS$'`

so that any accounts in the administrator group that do not match Administrator or ADMINS are added to that variable. https://regex101.com/ is a great site for learning Regex to use with match btw, if your interested.